# SASS issue with math.div and variables

Tags: sass

I am updating some SASS files to accommodate the division update, and running into an issue with the code.

Current code:

```
$spacer: 1rem !default;
$headings-margin-bottom: math.div($spacer, 2) !default;
```

This results in the following error in VSStudio 2019, using Web Compiler extension (1.12.394):

> Invalid CSS after "...bottom: math": expected expression (e.g. 1px,
> bold), was ".div($spacer, 2) !d"

I have tried researching this, but haven't found anything yet that helps.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same error here. did you find a solution?

Comment: @davideghz - i couldn't find any working solutions, so had to roll back the code.  i am hoping that the issue bubbles up in the sass community and is addressed in a future release.  until then, sticking with old-but-working code.

Comment: I googled and the problem seems to happen only on `node-sass`. I also rolled back to the old but working "slash" syntax e.g, `$spacer/2`

Comment: to close the loop on this issue - we removed node-sass and installed latest sass version, which includes libsass.  this update allows us to use the updated math.div functionality.  the biggest hassle to this was updating the supporting sass files in our version of bootstrap; we weren't ready to upgrade bootstap at the same time.  cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Check your environment and make sure that you are using `sass` package not `node-sass` or other flavors.

Also, make sure your sass version is higher than `v1.33.0`.

Comment: Thanks. node-sass instead of sass was my issue.